# Array indexes don't underatand why I have an exception and can't sort

Tags: java

I need to sort the array through this array of indexes. I don't understand why I have

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
> index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
> size of the array.

I also can't sort it with quicksort. I guess it's because I have an issue with curly braces?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] arr = {4, 3, 6, 2, 5};

    Integer[] index = new Integer[arr.length];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            {
                index[i] = i;
            }
            System.out.print(String.format("%d, ", arr[index[i]]));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(index));
        }
        int low = 0;
        int high = index.length;
        quickSort(index, low, high);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(index));
    }
}


 public static void quickSort (Integer[]index ,int low, int high){

        if (low >= high)
            return;
        // берем pivot
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int pivot = index[middle];
        // лево меньше pivot и право больше pivot
        int i = low, j = high;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (index[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }

            while (index[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = index[i];
                index[i] = index[j];
                index[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // рекурсируем две саб части
        if (low < j)
            quickSort(index, low, j);

        if (high > i)
            quickSort(index, i, high);
    }
}

4, [0, null, null, null, null]
3, [0, 1, null, null, null]
6, [0, 1, 2, null, null]
2, [0, 1, 2, 3, null]
5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Arr.main(Arr.java:10)
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is there a compilation or a runtime error (exception)?

Comment: What exception is thrown? And in which line?

Comment: i've added what shows compilator =)

Comment: Your `arr` array has length 5, correspondingly you initialize the `index` with length 5 (with allowed indexes 0 to 4). For `i == 5` where should the java runtime store the value for `index[i] = i;`?

Comment: so where should i store that value i mean 5 ?really can't get this

Comment: If you want to store the value 5 at index 5 you need an array that has at least a length of 6 (to store 6 values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). If you want to store 10 values in an array the array needs a length of 10 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

With

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)